# Get value from dictionaries in a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, for-loop

I have a dictionary of dictionaries with numbers inside.
I would like to get all numbers from different named dictionaries(string).

```
x={"stringdict1":{"number":56},"stringdictx":{"number":48}}
```

I'm looking for this: 56, 48.

It is not clear to me how I can get inside different "stringed" dictionaries.
I tried this (and a few other silly variations):

```
for numbers in dict[:]:
    print(numbers)
```

The problem for me is the different names(str) of the dictionary titles, but containing the same keys inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the dictionary `items` and check for the number key inside the sub-dictionaries.

```
for key, sub_dict in x.items():
    print(sub_dict['number'])
```

P.S. **Don't** use `dict` as variable name, you would overwrite the built-in functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so you will have to use nested for loop in order to get the inner value of a dictionary.
Try this:

```
x={"stringdict1":{"number":56},
   "stringdictx":{"number":48}}

for i in x:
    for j in x[i]:
        print(x[i][j])
```

Do let me know if you find a better solution, as this is not very efficient with respect to the time and space complexities :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't care about the keys in the outer dictionary, so iterate over the [values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values):

```
for v in x.values():
    print(v['number'])
```